# Orthonormal in vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $U$ is a subspace of a vector space $K$, $\{u_1,...,u_k\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $U$, $\{j_1,...,j_m\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $U^\perp $, Prove that $\{u_1,..,u_k,j_1,...,j_m\}$ is the orthonormal basis of $K$.

I don't know how to start off. Here are my a few thoughts on the problem.

suppose that $U$ is a k-dimensional subspace of m-dimensional vector space. Let $\{w_1,...,w_k\}$ is a basis of $U$ and $\{w_1,...,w_k,w_k+1,...,w_m\}$ be the extension of that basis to a basis of $K$. Note that $\{u_1,...,u_k\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $U$ and hence it spans $U$. Note that $U$ is k-dimensional hence $\{u_1,...,u_k\}$ is a basis for $U$. $\{j_1,...,j_m\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $U^\perp $ and suppose $\{j_1,...,j_m\}$ is the normalized Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization of $\{w_1,...,w_m\}$. Hence, $\{w_1,...,w_m\}$ is a basis of $K$.

I don't know how to continue. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: But why would the $j_i$ be the result of applying Gram-Schmidt to the $w_i$? You have to prove, just on the hypotheses, without any assumptions as to where the $j_i$ came from, that the $u_i$ together with the $j_i$ form a basis for $K$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two conditions for a basis to be orthonormal:

1. The vectors must have unit length.
2. The vectors must be perpendicular.

The first condition is automatically ok, since that is a condition on each vector, and you know both $\{u_1,\ldots,u_k\}$ and $\{j_1,\ldots,j_m\}$ are of unit length.

Second: perpendicular means that $a \cdot b = 0$ for all elements $a,b$ in the basis. You know if you take two $u_i$'s, then they are perpendicular. Also if you take two $j_i$'s, then they are perpendicualar.

What about $u_i \cdot j_i$?

**HINT** (mouseover)

> The $u_i$ live in $U$ and $j_i$ live in $U^\perp$...

Comment: $u_i.j_i = 0$ since they are orthogonal to each other? Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @needhelp Yes, correct. And that proves the statement.